# Does this look structural?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

[image]

My house is 5 years old and is a two story. This is on a ceiling upstairs in a vaulted area of my home. We have an attic but don’t use it for storage or anything. I can tell it’s the drywall but would this possibly be something related to structural or something I can easily fix? I am still under a 10 year structural warranty with the builder, so if it’s that, I want to have them fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a poorly done drywall joint to me. Could have been exacerbated by normal settling of the home. It's nearly impossible to tell if there are underlying structural issues, without inspecting the site.

Comment: A photo with a little context would help. I can't speculate what the framing looks like from this tight view, but my wild guess is that some truss lift has occurred at a girder or beam, tearing the joint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it to be a structural issue but a bad tape joint as @Tester101 mentioned in his comment. There's a slight possibility that this is a byproduct of a small roof leak too, tho not likely in a 5 year old home. Also, as @Tester101 mentioned, it's difficult to say without being able to physically inspect the structure ourselves.

Bubbles in taped joints are caused by not having enough mud behind the joint tape. If I were to fix this, I'd cut out most of that seam and redo it.

Comment: I know the photo isn’t the greatest. I had to really crop it in order for the website to post it. My hubby walked around and didn’t see a leak. I’ll let him know what you have suggested.

Comment: As I stated, a leak is a possibility, but more than likely not the issue on a 5 year old home. Still a possibility tho...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like buckling to me. Could be the result of the drywall absorbing moisture, or it could be movement in the frame of the house. If the frame is moving, there is nothing easy you can do to fix it. If it is a moisture issue, then you would need to figure out why there is excessive moisture in the ceiling and eliminate the source of the moisture or dry it somehow.

You can determine if there is buckling by getting access to the joists above the ceiling and laying a framing level across them. If they are bending, it will be obvious.